# HTML5 canvas stroke overlapping

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, overlap, stroke

Here I create a line-path and stroke with path, but there is no overlapping with stroke which I need:

CODE and DEMO: http://jsbin.com/yepigu/12/edit?output

```
ctx.strokeStyle='yellowgreen';
  drawPolyline(pts);
```

Everything is fine but as you can see, I cant see y stroke overlapping

How I can change this example to show overlapping with stroke?

Comment: You're drawing a single polyline so the intersections will be blended rather than creating overlaps. ;-)

Comment: ok, but how I can make it possible ?

Comment: You draw individual lines instead of one polyline.

Comment: Can you please show the fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You can draw your red-outlined, pink-filled, blue-stroked polyline that shows the overlaps in each line segment.

[image]

The key is to draw each line segment individually instead of drawing it in a single path. Also, draw the red, pink & blue parts of the line from the thickest to the thinnest.

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var pts=[{x:50,y:50},{x:200,y:200},{x:50,y:200},{x:200,y:50}];

ctx.lineCap='round';
ctx.lineJoin='round';

drawPolyline(pts);


function drawPolyline(pts){
  for(var i=1;i<pts.length;i++){
    //
    ctx.lineWidth=25;
    ctx.strokeStyle='red';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(pts[i-1].x,pts[i-1].y);
    ctx.lineTo(pts[i].x,pts[i].y);
    ctx.stroke();
    //
    ctx.lineWidth=22;
    ctx.strokeStyle='pink';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(pts[i-1].x,pts[i-1].y);
    ctx.lineTo(pts[i].x,pts[i].y);
    ctx.stroke();
    //
    ctx.lineWidth=3;
    ctx.strokeStyle='blue';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(pts[i-1].x,pts[i-1].y);
    ctx.lineTo(pts[i].x,pts[i].y);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=600 height=600></canvas>
```

Comment: Sigh...then you should rewrite your question in a way that more clearly describes what you need.